# Page won't load, advice to update Adobe Flash Player doesn't help

Tags: windows-vista, firefox, internet, flash-player

My computer is a Hewlett-Packard Vista with a Firefox browser. I have been setting up with a company to work from home and when I was supposed to connect with my telephone system the page loaded a couple of times and now it won't load.

The company said that maybe I need to download the latest adobe flash player.  I have tried to do that several times and it doesn't want to load either; says I have one downloaded so I uninstalled the older programs and it still won't work.  Other sites load just fine.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! There is a bit of a lack of details for us to help you further, can you include the following information: By telephone system, do you mean you are using a dial-up connection at home? What of the page doesn't load and what (error) do you see? Does a [Flash Test](http://www.adobe.com/software/flash/about/) says it is successfully installed? Have you tried a different browser?

Answer (score 0):

I've been running into similar problems.  Preliminary debugging indicated that Adobe was/is requesting overlapping chunks like (1-1,4012-4230,4016-4400...) when running in a tab.  Things I have done which seem to work are:

- In Firefox, open `Tools->Options->Applications`.  Change the application for `Adobe Acrobat Document` to `Use Adobe Reader 9.4 (default)`.
- In Adobe, open `Edit->Preferences->Internet`.   Uncheck `Allow fast web view`.

Either of these seem to work.  My wife prefers the first fix which open Adobe outside the browser.  The second works when opening documents in the browser.  I run through the Firefox and Adobe debugging pages, although I didn't edit the Registry.  Both of them slow the initial document display down, as more of the document needs to be read.